# XPath assistance

Tags: xslt, xml

I created an XSLT translation for XML that looks like this that was workign as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bsar:BSAForm xmlns:bsar="http://www.fincen.gov/bsa/bsar/2011-06-01">
    <bsar:FilingInstitutionInformation>
        <bsar:PrimaryRegulator>D</bsar:PrimaryRegulator>
        ...
    </bsar:FilingInstitutionInformation>
    ...
</bsar:BSAForm>
```

The translation looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="text" />
      <xsl:template match="bsar:BSAForm">

        <!--Output Filing Institution Information Record-->
        <xsl:call-template name="FileInstActivity"/>

        ...

      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="FileInstActivity">
           <xsl:value-of select="bsar:PrimaryRegulator"/>
           ...
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works as expected and shows the following output:

```
D
```

Now, I am finding that my input XML will looks like the following instead, but I'm having some trouble adjusting the xpath accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form version="2.0">
<meta>
    <field name="ID">54</field>
    <field name="Title">SAR 2012 #1</field>
    <field name="Assigned_x0020_To">MEMENTO-INC\memento_admin</field>
    <field name="Status">1; Open</field>
    <field name="Form_x0020_Type">9; SAR 2012</field>
    <field name="Alert">1</field>
    <field name="Due_x0020_Date">9999-12-31T23:59:59</field>
    <field name="Is_x0020_Complete">False</field>
    <field name="ValidationMessages">Memento.Forms.Core.Messages</field>
    <field name="Closed" />
    <field name="ClosedBy" />
    <field name="editMaster" />
    <field name="dateOfInitialDetection">9999-12-31T23:59:59</field>
    <field name="dataBlobXml">
        &lt;bsar:BSAForm xmlns:bsar="http://www.fincen.gov/bsa/bsar/2011-06-01"&gt;
        &lt;bsar:FilingInstitutionInformation&gt;
        &lt;bsar:PrimaryRegulator>D&gt;%lt;/&gt;
        ...
    </field>
</meta>
</form>
```

No matter how I edit the xpath of my template (bsar:BSAForm), it seems to keep showing all the text from the other field sections, as well as the rest of the XML (I'm working on the issue with the 
     & lt; 
and 
     & gt;
but that's another issue):

```
54SAR 2012 #1MEMENTO-INC\memento_admin1; Open9; SAR 201219999-12-31T23:59:59FalseMemento.Forms.Core.Messages9999-12-31T23:59:59
        <bsar:BSAForm xmlns:bsar="http://www.fincen.gov/bsa/bsar/2011-06-01">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried, and what do you want the output to look like? The second XML schema is substantially different from the first, and it's not clear what you expect.

Comment: I honestly don't see how your question relates to SharePoint.

Comment: The XML is coming from a Sharepoint list item

Comment: In my post it is noted what is expected: This works as expected and shows the following output:
D

Answer (score 2):

You can reach the text inside dataBlobXml using the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="field[@name='dataBlobXml']">
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

But this will come as text node into the template. So if you want to parse it further, you will have to either use string functions (like `substring-before` and `substring-after`) or perform second XSLT transformation (i.e. pass results of the first transformation to the second one).

First approach can be implemented using the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="field[@name='dataBlobXml']">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'&lt;bsar:PrimaryRegulator&gt;'),'&lt;/')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(not tested, but hopefully you've got the idea)

P.S. Based on my understanding this question doesn't relate to SharePoint directly and I myself voted to close it as offtopic, but since in SharePoint we frequently have to deal with XSLT, I think this answer might be useful for the site members anyway.